# Solr - Collections API timeouts

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I've got a setup with 3x zoo keeper's and 4x solrcloud node's.

This is all working, all nodes are seeing each other and I initially had a default collection.

From there, I used the collections API to create a new collection which successfully completed and all it's successfully sharded across 2 nodes, with the other 2 being used for replica's. I can also successfully save documents to that collection. Browsing the solr web GUI on any of the boxes all works, no speed issues.

However, anytime I try to use the collections API I get timeouts. Creating a new collection, reloading one of the existing collections, deleting a collection... all of them timeout.

Any thoughts on why would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: What is your solr version? Are there your nodes at different physical machine or virtual machine? Could you give detailed information? :)

Comment: Solr 4.7.0. Nodes are different physical machines, as are zoo keepers. Ended up figuring out the problem - one of the zoo keepers knew about the rest, but the other two didn't have their zoo.cfg referencing all other zoo keeper instances.

Comment: Did you examine solr and zookeeper logs? Are there any exception in the logs?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Ended up being Zoo Keeper config mismatch

Comment: What miss match you were having there.. I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: Can you please describe the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced similar issue:

```
Solr process 24214 running on port 8983
Failed to get system information from http://localhost:8983/solr/ due to: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: clusterstatus the collection time out:180s
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:537)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:471)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$StatusTool.getCloudStatus(SolrCLI.java:721)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$StatusTool.reportStatus(SolrCLI.java:704)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$StatusTool.runTool(SolrCLI.java:662)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:215)
```

So to solve this issue I have followed given instruction and resolved it.:

- Stop all Solr instances
- Stop all Zookeeper instances
- Start all Zookeeper instances
- Start Solr instances one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Such timeout can occur when Solr is not able to obtain cluster state. If following call is results in timeout, then this is the case

```
http://solr-hostname:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=json
```

This may be caused by incorrect entries present in `/clusterstate.json`

**To fix this:**

- get clusterstate from ZooKeeper by calling

  ```
  zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd get /clusterstate.json > clusterstate.json
  ```
- edit extracted `clusterstate.json` file and remove sections with wrong IPs or not existing hosts
- clear the clusterstate in ZooKeeper by calling

  ```
  zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd clear /clusterstate.json
  ```
- save corrected state in ZooKeeper by sending updated JSON file

  ```
  zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd putfile /clusterstate.json ./clusterstate.json`
  ```
- restart Solr instances

After that, if your clusterstate shows correct info, you should no longer have timeouts when accessing Collections API.

**Note**

Be careful when editing clusterstate JSON, limit your changes only to removing not existing hosts/replicas/shards.

Answer (score 0):

I also had timeout issues with the collections API. To fix this problem, I added the server's IP address to the solr.xml file that you find in /var/solr/data/solr.xml. My setup consists of 3 Ubuntu servers that run ZooKeeper (3.4.6) and SolrCloud (5.2.1) on each server.