# Solr 4.7.1 CREATEALIAS times out

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using Solr 4.7.1 with Zookeeper 3.4.6, 2 Solr servers with 3 Zookeeper instance, and would like to create some aliases of our collections.  However, calls to CREATEALIAS are failing with the following:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">500</int>
    <int name="QTime">180045</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="error">
    <str name="msg">createalias the collection time out:180s</str>
    <str name="trace">
      org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: createalias the collection time out:180s 
      at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:252) 
      at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:233) 
      at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateAliasAction(CollectionsHandler.java:311)       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:157) 
      at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) 
      at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:720) 
      at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:265) 
      at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:205) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) 
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) 
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) 
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) 
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) 
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) 
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) 
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    </str>
    <int name="code">500</int>
  </lst>
</response>
```

I am creating the alias by calling the following URL:

```
http://<MYSERVER:PORT>/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=<ALIAS_NAME>&collections=<COLLECTION_NAME>
```

Where  is the hostname and port of one of my Solr servers in the SolrCloud.  Why would this timeout, and how do I get it to work?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have a similar issue with the CREATE action.

Comment: Sorry, I never did get an answer.  I actually don't work there anymore, and I honestly don't remember what we did to get around it.

Comment: No problem. I found out why I got those timeouts. I posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626858/solr-collections-api-timeouts